# Get the value of a process executed in a child back to parent

Tags: perl, fork

I'm looking for a solution which allows me to return the values of a process executed in a child back to the parent process. Currently i try this but have no idea where to hook the return value:

```
use Proc::ProcessTable;
use POSIX qw(:signal_h :errno_h :sys_wait_h);
$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;

for my $count (1..10) {  # start a few demo childs
 if (fork () == 0) {
  &startChild;
  exit 0;
 }     
}

do  {
 print "Working\n";
 sleep 1;
} while (chkChildProcess());

sub startChild {
  print "Starting Child $$\n";
  system("date"); #==>Need to get the output of "date" back to parent
  sleep 2 + rand 7; 
  print "End  Child $$\n";
}

sub chkChildProcess {
 for my $p (@{new Proc::ProcessTable->table}){
  if ($p->ppid == $$){
   $curPID{$$}=$p->pid;
   return 1;
  }
 }
 return undef;
}


sub REAPER {
my $pid;
$pid = waitpid(-1, &WNOHANG);
if ($pid == -1) {
 # no child waiting.  Ignore it.
} elsif (WIFEXITED($?)) {
 print "Process $pid exited.\n";
} else {
 print "False alarm on $pid.\n";
}
$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;          # in case of unreliable signals
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Getting the output of `system` back to the parent is your second problem.  Getting it to the child is the first problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bg_eval` and `bg_qx` methods of [`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper) were made to solve this problem.

```
use Forks::Super 'bg_eval';

my @result;
for my $count (1 .. 10) {

    $result[$count] = bg_eval {
        my $date = `date`;
        sleep 2 + rand 7;
        return $date;
    };
}

print "$result[$_]\n" for 1..10;
```

The block after `bg_eval` is run asynchronously in a background process. When the background process is finished, the variable `$result[$count]` will be populated with the result.

When you print `$result[$_]`, one of two things will happen. If the background process associated with that variable is finished, it will contain its return value. If the background process is not finished, it will wait for the process to finish, and then make the return value available in that value.

Comment: Forks::Super looks very interesting but the above sample returns Can't return outside a subroutine at sfork.pl line 9, <DATA> line 261.

Comment: @Joe - my bad. The first line needs to be `use Forks::Super 'bg_eval'` so the `bg_eval` function is imported to your namespace.

Comment: wow, that becomes very interesting. I first thought it doesn't work because i got a few errors during the installation using cpan. There seems to be many dependencies using Forks::Super. Will play with this tonight ...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you may want to use [Parallel::ForkManager](http://p3rl.org/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager), returning the value from the child via the data_structure_reference parameter of the finish method to a run_on_finish callback in the parent.

To capture the output, the easiest way is to use [IPC::System::Simple](http://p3rl.org/IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple)'s capture or capturex.

Comment: IPC::System::Simple looks interesting but all executes within the child end up with "No child processes" no matter if the shell was involved or not, thanks anyway..

Comment: maybe resulting from your CHLD handler (may interfere with either or both of the modules I suggested, which deal with their own children)

Answer (score 1):

you could use [threads::shared](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html) instead of fork, create a shared variable, lock it and write into it. keep in mind that locking is reeeally slow!

See also [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=579444) post on perlmonks on why locking the variable is necessary.

Comment: creating threads instead of forking is reeeeally slow; locking is much less so.

Comment: I'd like to run the application constantly in some kind of a endless loop. It turned out that Threads are not made for this since there is a memory issue with this.